# Bokeh: changing circle size in hover callback

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, hover, bokeh

I am new to this superb tool that is Bokeh for Python. I use Python 2.7 and Bokeh 0.10.

I am trying to do a basic plot:

- two data series
- 'simultaneous hovering': the two series points that have same abscissa are both displaying something
- when hovered over, the two selected points are highlighted: they become bigger, the other get a fill_alpha to 0.2

I tried a lot of stuff, with mixed results.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Circle, HoverTool, CustomJS

output_file("callback.html")

#data definition
x = np.arange(100)
y = 20 + 10 * np.random.uniform(size = 100)
y2 = 20 + 10 * np.random.uniform(size = 100)

label1 = np.arange(100)


#sources creation
source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            label  = label1
        )
    )

source2 = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            x=x,
            y=y2,
            label  = label1
        )
    )

hover = HoverTool(
        tooltips=[

            ("label", "@label")
        ]
    )


p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=800, tools=[hover,'box_zoom,resize,wheel_zoom,reset'],
           title="Mouse over the dots")


circle1 = Circle(x='x', y='y', radius=20, fill_color='red',fill_alpha = 1)
circle2 = Circle(x='x', y='y2', radius=20,fill_color = 'green',fill_alpha = 1)
circle1_grey = Circle(x='x', y='y', radius=2, fill_color='red',fill_alpha = 0.2)
circle2_grey = Circle(x='x', y='y', radius=2, fill_color='green',fill_alpha = 0.2)


cr = p.add_glyph(source, circle1_grey, selection_glyph=circle1, nonselection_glyph=circle1_grey)
cr2 = p.add_glyph(source2, circle2_grey, selection_glyph=circle2, nonselection_glyph=circle2_grey)


callback = CustomJS(args={'sourceA': source, 'sourceB' : source2}, code="""
        var dataA = sourceA.get('data');
        var dataB = sourceB.get('data');
        var f = cb_data['index'];


        sourceA.set('selected', f);
        sourceB.set('selected', f);
        sourceA.trigger('change');
        sourceB.trigger('change');
    """)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback, renderers=[cr,cr2], mode='vline'))


show(p)
```

With this solution, several points make me unhappy:

- the circles do not becomme bigger when selected. I tried to do it in the callback, but I did not get it right either.
- when zooming, points are becoming too big and start to overlap. To tackle this issue, working with 'size = 20' works, but then the 'mode=vline' starts to fail: hovering is too thick and always selects several points. I tried to mix size=20 and radius = 2 but it did not work either.
- I did not manage to add a legend (but I can make it on my own).

apart from these issues, I am very pleased with Bokeh! thanks a lot for developing this library & helping noobs like me.

t.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the solution would be something like this. But I think the

```py
# [...]

hover_init_data = {
    'x': [],
    'y': []
}
self.hover_source = ColumnDataSource(data=hover_init_data)

# these are the bigger circles
c = self.plot.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    size=10,
    fill_color='black',
    line_color=None,
    source=self.hover_source,
)
c.selection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_color='black',
)
c.nonselection_glyph = Circle(
    fill_color='black',
)

hover_callback = CustomJS(
    args={'source': self.source, 'hover_source' : self.hover_source}, 
    code='''
        console.log(cb_data);
        var inds = cb_data['index'].indices;
        console.log(inds);
        var s = source.data;
        var h = hover_source.data;

        h['x'] = []
        h['y'] = []
        for (i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) { // You can limit the number of overlapped points here
            h['x'].push(s['x'][inds[i]])
            h['y'].push(s['y'][inds[i]])
        }
        hover_source.change.emit();
    ''',
)

hover = HoverTool(
    callback=hover_callback,
    renderers=[main_circle_renderer],   // if there are more than one renderer the callback is not triggered
    tooltips="""
        <b>x: </b> @x <br>
        <b>y: </b> @y <br>
    """,
)

# [...]
```

**Note**: Check this [old issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2328) as well, there are pending several improvements